# How to get datasource while MyBatis executing a SQL?

Tags: java, spring, mybatis

I am using MyBatis Interceptor to capture the SQL to be executed. However, I am not able to get the datasource that is going to execute the SQL.
Is there a way in Java that I can get the specific dataSource?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution after some time. By implementing MyBatis's Interceptor interface, we could get the mappedStatement every time we execute a SQL. From mappedStatement, the dataSource could be obtained.

```
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DatasourceInterceptor.class);

@Override
public Object intercept(Invocation invocation) throws Throwable {
    Object target = invocation.getTarget();
    Object result;
    Optional<DataSource> dataSourceOpt = Optional.empty();
    if (target instanceof Executor) {
        MappedStatement mappedStatement = (MappedStatement) invocation.getArgs()[0];
        if (mappedStatement.getConfiguration() != null
                && mappedStatement.getConfiguration().getEnvironment() != null) {
            dataSourceOpt = Optional.of(mappedStatement.getConfiguration().getEnvironment().getDataSource());
        }  
        Object parameter = invocation.getArgs()[1];
        BoundSql boundSql = mappedStatement.getBoundSql(parameter);
        String sql = boundSql.getSql();
        logger.debug("executor SQL:{}", sql);
    }  
    result = invocation.proceed();
    return result; 
}
```